# What is the simplest way to do "SELECT TOP 5" for multiple parameters?

Tags: sql, hsqldb, libreoffice-base

I'm trying to build a new database in LibreOffice Base / HSQLDB which supposedly supports standard SQL, but probably not quite as widely as SQL-server or Oracle.

I've got a table of scores, where the participant is a member of one of a list of clubs. I need to generate "Team Scores" where the teams are dynamic, namely they consist of the top 5 scores from each club.

The closest I have been able to achieve so far is:

```
SELECT "Score", "ShootRecords"."ClubID" FROM  "ShootRecords" WHERE "ShootRecords"."ClubID" = 0

UNION 

SELECT "Score", "ShootRecords"."ClubID" FROM  "ShootRecords" WHERE "ShootRecords"."ClubID" = 1

ORDER BY "Score" DESC
```

If I add a `TOP 5`  qualifier to the start of each sub-query, it reports as invalid SQL.
If I move the `ORDER BY` clause into the sub-query, again it reports as invalid SQL, but each sub-query needs to be sorted that way, and restricted to `TOP 5` or the results are wrong.

I've also looked at doing sub-queries like so:

```
SELECT "ClubID"

FROM   "Clubs"

WHERE  "Clubs"."ClubID" IN

   (SELECT "ClubID"

    FROM "Clubs", "ShootRecords"

    WHERE "Clubs"."ClubID" = "ShootRecords"."ClubID"
    )
```

but again the ordering and sub-setting is done in the wrong order, or isn't valid.

What I am hoping to see would look something like:

```
Score     ClubID
------------------
300        0
299        0
280        0
200        0
190        0
310        1
290        1
277        1
```

etc.

Comment: Should be pretty simple to do. Please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `ORDER BY "Score" DESC LIMIT 5` to each unioned query ? ([ref](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_slicing)). Also, I think a `UNION ALL` would be better in this case.

Comment: Also, `TOP 5` is not standard SQL. Append `LIMIT 5` (that is also not standard, but well supported).

Comment: `LIMIT 5` isn't  standard SQL either; `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS` is. But, yes, HSQLDB  wants `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: What to do in case of ties? Pick a member from the tied ones arbitrarily I guess?

Comment: According [this page](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html) hsqldb supports also ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: @The Impaler:  `TOP 5`  works in a stand-alone query, appending `LIMIT 5` doesn't work here - not valid.
@Thorsten - one thing at a time!

Comment: Both `LIMIT 5` and `ORDER BY` give me an `Unexpected token` error if I add them to the second sub-query, but work fine, (albeit limited) on the first sub-query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner actually, ties at this level don't matter in the slightest - the total team score (which I hadn't mentioned yet) is what I was after, so it doesn't matter who achieves it.

Comment: I don't understand. If a team has these scores: 500, 400, 300, 200, 200, 200, 100, you want to do something about the tying 200, supposedly retrieve it twice, so you get five scores 500, 400, 300, 200, 200. Correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Excactly right - I want to select the five best scores, regardless of who achieved them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your own query work, you'd want an `ORDER BY` (and `LIMIT`) clause per partial query. In order to do so, use parentheses:

```
(
  SELECT Score, ClubID 
  FROM ShootRecords 
  WHERE ShootRecords.ClubID = 0
  ORDER BY Score DESC
  LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT Score, ClubID 
  FROM ShootRecords 
  WHERE ShootRecords.ClubID = 1
  ORDER BY Score DESC
  LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY ClubID, Score DESC;
```

It's `UNION ALL` by the way. `UNION [DISTINCT]` is a special form of union that removes duplicates.

Comment: This was it - the first time I had seen an example of `UNION` with brackets placed around the sub-queries. The rest was pretty much fine, just not being parsed as two distinct queries.

Answer (score 0):

TOP n queries per group are usually solved with analytic functions, but HSQLDB  doesn't support them.

Anyway, to be among the top five means there are less than five better.

```
select *
from  shootrecords sr
where 5 >
(
  select count(*)
  from shootrecords better
  where better.clubid = sr
  and 
  (  better.score > sr.score
      or 
    (better.score = sr.score and better.memberid < sr.memberid) -- for the case of ties
  )
)
order by clubid, score, memberid;
```

In case of a tie (multiple members with the same score) I must pick members arbitrarily. I pick those with the lowest IDs first.